# Does anyone have a list of Chabad yeshiva gedolas?

Tags: chabad, yeshiva-school

I'm looking for a list of Chabad yeshivas. I need some help compiling it, as I didn't go to a Lubavitch Mesivta.

Comment: Where did you go for mesivta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mendy here are some Yeshivos (older list) I suggest you get advice from a Chabad Shliach and older bochurim about what’s the best option for you. I learned in TT Morristown, NJ coming from Ner Yisroel Baltimore Mesivta. I really recommended it, specially if you’re coming from a litvish Yeshiva. https://www.rca.edu/?mobile_version=false

California
Yeshiva Ohr Elchonon
Chabad
Rosh Yeshiva: Rabbi Ezra Shochet
Mashgiach: Rabbi Chaim Zev Citron
7215 Waring Ave.
Los Angeles, CA 90046 Phone: 323-937-3763 Fax: 323-937-9456 Email: yoec@anet.net

Florida
Yeshiva Gedolah Miami
Rosh Yeshiva: Rabbi Y. L. Shapiro Mashgiach: Rabbi A. Korf
1140 Alton Road
Miami Beach, FL 33139
Phone: 305-673-5664
Fax: 305-531-7590
Email: bckorf@yahoo.com Founded 1974

Maryland
Yeshivas Lubavitch
D'Baltimore
Mashpia: Rabbi Nochum Bukiet
6702 Park Heights Ave Baltimore, MD 21215 Phone: 443-379-0921 Email: ewebs7@aol.com Founded 2005

Minnesota
Lubavitch Rabbinical
College of Minnesota/
Machon Lehorah
Menahel: Rabbi Nachman Wilhelm
P.O. Box #11178
S. Paul, MN 55111
Phone: 651-642-9122
Fax: 651-917-9283
Email: lubavitchyeshiva@yahoo.com Founded 1992

New Jersey
Yeshivas Tomchei Tmimim
Dean: Rabbi Moshe Herson Menahel: Rabbi Sholom Spalter Mashpai: Rabbi E. Zweibel
226 Sussex Avenue Morristown, NJ 07960
Phone: 973-984-6326
Fax: 973-267-6921 Founded 1958

New York
Central Yeshiva Tomchei
Tmimim Lubavitch
Rosh Yeshiva: Rabbi Z. Labkowski Mashpia: Rabbi Shlomo Zarchi
770 Eastern Parkway
Brooklyn, NY 11213
Phone: 718-859-7600
Fax: 718-859-2331 Founded 1940

Yeshivos Gedolos (English Speaking Countries)

Hadar HaTorah (Baalei Teshuva)
Rabbinical Seminary
Rosh yeshiva: Rabbi Y. Goldberg Menahel: Rabbi Y. Silberstein Director: Rabbi Sholom B. Hecht 824 Eastern Parkway
Brooklyn, NY 11213
Phone: 718-735-0205
Fax: 718-735-4455
Email: hadarh@ix.netcom.com Founded 1966

Jewish Technical
Vocational School
Dean: Rabbi Levi Kaplan
Mailing Address:
784 Eastern Prkwy Suite 304 Brooklyn, NY 11213 Phone: 718-877-3528 Email: info@jtvs.org Founded 2008

Talmudical Seminary
Oholei Torah
Rosh Yeshiva:
Rabbi Yisroel Freidman Menahel: Rabbi Y. Lesches
Exec Dir: Rabbi Yosef Rosenfeld 668 Eastern Parkway
Brooklyn, NY 11213
Phone: 718-735-1077
Fax: 718-604-2563
Founded 1970

Australia
Rabbinical College of
Australia and New Zealand
Rosh Yeshiva:
Rabbi Binyamin Cohen Director: Rabbi Avrohom Procel 67 Alexandra Street
East St. Kilda, Victoria 3183 AUSTRALIA
Phone: 61-3-9525-9165
Fax: 61-3-9525-9970
Founded 1966

Yeshiva Gedolah
Rabbinical College
Director: Rabbi Pinchos Feldman
36 Flood Street
Bondi, NSW 2026 AUSTRALIA
Phone: 61-2-9387-3822 Fax: 61-2-9387-574
Email: info@yeshiva.org.au

Canada
Rabbinical College of Quebec-Tomchei Tmimim Lubavitch Bais Medrash
Rosh Yeshiva: Rabbi A. L Kaplan
Director: Rabbi Chaim Langsam
6355 Westbury Avenue
Montreal, Quebec H3W 1G7 CANADA
Phone: 514-227-7770 ext:11
Fax: 514-344-9551
Email: chaimlangsam@yahoo.com Founded 1942
Yeshiva Gedolah

United Kingdom
Yeshiva Gedolah Lubavitch
Rosh Yeshiva: Rabbi Y.M. Hertz Mashpia: Rabbi Mendel Gordon 3-5 Kingsley Way
London, N2 0EH
UNITED KINGDOM
Phone: 44-18-1458-2312
Fax: 44-18-1731-7120

Yeshivas Lubavitch
Manchester
Rosh Yeshiva: Rabbi Y.A. Cohen Menahel: Rabbi S. Weiss
62 Singelton RD
Salford
Lancashire M7 4LU UNITED KINGDOM Phone: 44-161-740-4243 Email: manchesty@aol.com Founded 1978